# Is Brahmaputra the only river with masculine name?

Tags: name, rivers

Normally we have all major rivers in Bharat with feminine names for instance: **Ganga, Yamuna, Saraswati, Godavari, Narmada, Gomti** etc but Brahmaputra seems to be an exception with masculine name.

My questions:

1. Why a river with masculine name?
2. Is there any other major river with masculine name?

Comment: Why not?  नद (Nada) is masculine or male while नदि  (Nadi) is feminine or female, like Deva and Devi.

Answer (score 2):

Appearantly, the “Sindhu” is also regarded as a male river:

> sindhu    m.  and f. (prob. fr.1. sidh-,"to go") a river, stream (especially the indu-s, and in this sense said to be the only river regarded as m.See -nada-, column 2) etc. View this entry on the original dictionary page scan.
>
> http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=sindhu&lang=sans&action=Search

Also Viśāla is sometimes mentioned as a river in its masculine form, such as in the Apte’s “practical Sanskrit-English dictionary”:

> [http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=viśāla](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=vi%C5%9B%C4%81la)
>   https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/vishala#sanskrit

The Varaha Purana also mentions some rivers that take a masculine form:

> Śoṇa (शोण)
>
> [http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=śoṇa](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=%C5%9Bo%E1%B9%87a)
>   https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/shona#purana
>
> Mahāvaktra (महावक्त्र)
>
> [http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=mahāvaktra](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=mah%C4%81vaktra)
>   https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/mahavaktra#purana
>
> Kṣīroda (क्षीरोद)
>
> [http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=kṣīroda](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=k%E1%B9%A3%C4%ABroda)
>   https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kshiroda#purana

Comment: Maybe coz these are not well known rivers that's why we are not aware of them.

Answer (score 1):

No. In sanskrit नद('Nada') means a rivers whose name is masculine and नदी ('Nadi') means a river with feminine name.Reference : [http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=नद&lang=sans&action=Search](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%A6&lang=sans&action=Search)

There are many rivers with masculin names in India. Please check the list:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rivers_of_India